# Using Google Analytics within an Editor (Google Docs) sidebar add-on

Tags: google-apps-script, google-analytics, google-apps-marketplace

Trying to get visibility to the number of add-on users and their behaviors while using a google docs sidebar add-on I created.

I've included Global site tag (gtag.js) in `sidebar.html` yet there are no hits in the Real-Time overview, and no event hits when I click buttons that I've added event listners too.

Is there a special process/methodology for adding analytics to add-ons? There is nothing I can find within the add-on documentation.

#### sidebar.html:

```html
<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-XXXXXXXXX-X"></script>
<script>
window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
gtag('js', new Date());

gtag('config', 'UA-XXXXXXXXX-X');
</script>

....

....

<script>
$('#button111').click(function(){
   gtag('event', 'query');
});
</script>
```

Comment: thanks to @michele-pisani for link to [add-on analytics documentation](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/application-development/google-apps-script-tracking-add-on)

Comment: here is the code i ended up with https://gist.github.com/dwanderton/535a5f5339a5f3b6dcd3fd0d5956fac5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use **Measurement Protocol**: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1

You can find here an example on how to use it for Apps Script. In this case it is used to track user accesses and actions in Google Analytics in a Spreadsheet, but the general concept on how to send hits to Analytics is the same:

https://www.appsscript.it/tutorial/tracciare-in-google-analytics-gli-accessi-e-le-azioni-degli-utenti-in-uno-spreadsheet/

Using Analytics snippet you need to specify page and title because HTMLService interfaces prevents the tracking code from doing its usual automatic detection:

```
<script type="text/javascript">var GA = '<?= ga ?>';</script> //...
 <script async="" src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=YOUR_TRACKING_ID" type="text/javascript"></script> <script 
type="text/javascript">window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'YOUR_TRACKING_ID',{
  'page_title': 'CUSTOM_TITLE',
  'page_location': SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getUrl()
});</script>
```

Comment: This looks like it would work, any ideas as to why including `gtag` in the html does not?

Comment: I added more info in the post.

Comment: unfortunately no luck with either of the two methods :( did you previously implement successfully?

Comment: The example in the link, to track user accesses and actions in Google Analytics in a Spreadsheet, is mine. Are you sure it doesn't depend on google analytics?  Also try reading this article: https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/application-development/google-apps-script-tracking-add-on (there are issues related to cookies, but also here it talks about the measurement protocol).